# Identity matrix stacking in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I need a `2n x n` matrix in NumPy consisting of the `n x n` identity matrix and the negative `n x n` identity matrix stacked on top of one another.

This was my original solution, which works fine.

```
def id_stack(n): 
    id_ = np.identity(n) 
    return np.vstack((id_, -id_))

id_stack(3)
# array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
#        [-1., -0., -0.],
#        [-0., -1., -0.],
#        [-0., -0., -1.]])
```

Then I figured I could just set the diagonals instead and be faster like this, which also works.

```
def id_stack2(n): 
    full = np.zeros((2*n, n)) 
    rng = np.arange(n) 
    full[rng, rng] = 1 
    full[rng + n, rng] = -1     
    return full
```

I was wondering if there is an even faster way of accomplishing this, maybe using some kind of stride tricks?

Comment: Stride tricks may not be faster, but yes, you could use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably noticed from your own examples, allocating one big buffer and setting elements in it is generally faster than allocating two smaller buffers and a big buffer to copy them into.

The neat thing about numpy is that you can get views to the same buffer without allocating a new array. For example:

```
 output = np.zeros((2 * n, n))
```

A useful view in this case is

```
flat = output.ravel()
```

You can set every `n + 1`st element to 1, starting from the first, for a total of `n` elements in the flattened view, and similar for -1. This requires only a simple indexing operation on the raveled view:

```
output[:n * n:n + 1] = 1
output[n * n::n + 1] = -1
```

This avoids creating the full range arrays, and triggering advanced indexing semantics, which are more memory intensive as well.

Comment: @EricHansen. That's the most basic way of indexing :)